# How to polyfill Promise in angular cli project?

Tags: angular, safari, promise, angular-cli, polyfills

On Safari 5.1.7 I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Promise` from `vendor.bundle.js` from blank new angular-cli project. I tried adding

```
import 'core-js/es6/promise';
```

or

```
import PolyFillPromise from 'core-js/es6/promise';
Promise = Promise ? Promise : PolyFillPromise;
```

in `polyfills.ts`, no change.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support. Safari 5 is not listed.